# A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found: only with distribution

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, distribution, provisioning

I'm releasing a new version of my iphone app and everything was going great until I changed the settings to "distribution" and "device", and then got the error:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

This doesn't make sense as I am able to install the app onto my phone in debug or release mode, but not in distribution mode.  Is this error because the provisioning profile and distribution profile are not compatible?  Or what could be a solution?

Back history... I DID just get a new iPhone 4 a month ago and this is the first distribution I have done with this device.  Xcode is also telling me:

> The iPhone “X” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.
>   Click “Install and Run” to install the provisioning profile “Y Distribution Profile” on “X iPhone” and continue running “Z.app”.

Can anyone help?  I'm going nuts and tired of running into a wall.  Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I needed to do was "build" instead of "build and run"

Comment: So I can not run the executable on my iPhone ?

Answer (score 2):

I use the distribution provisioning profile and found that the apps are not put on device with the distribution profile.

Answer (score 1):

Distribution profiles aren't used to put on devices i believe? I've only ever used the distribution to build to upload to the app store. 
When you get a new device you also need to remember to add it to the profile and then redownload it.

Answer (score 1):

1-Xcode->Click your app -> TARGETS -> click the app-> Build Setting-> Code Signing : Make sure that both "Debug" and "Any iOS SDK" are set to "iPhone Development"

2- Xcode -> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme: Make sure "Build Configuration" is set to “Debug".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run your app on a device using the distribution profile, which is really used for uploading the app to App Store [for distribution]. However, if you want to "simulate" how the app would behave in a production environment, what you need is a so-called "Ad-Hoc Provisioning Profile", which is really a lot like a distribution profile, but will allow the app to run only on designated devices without the need for XCode.

Check this link out for more detailed info.

[Exporting Your App for Testing (iOS, tvOS, watchOS)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. When building for Distribution, make sure you select "Build", not "Build & Go".